# How to check if an item in an array has been removed and delete it?

Tags: laravel

I have a question that has options like multiple choice options for answering, those options are what is inside the array, if someone removes an option while editing and saves the question, I'm not sure how to check for that, my code checks for editing an existing option and checks for adding a new option.

This is my code for the update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = SurveyQuestion::findOrFail($id);
    $preg->question = $request->question;
    $preg->survey_section_id = $request->survey_section_id;
    $preg->response_type_id = $request->response_type_id;
    $preg->optional = $request->optional;
    $preg->save();

    if ($request->get('questionOptions')) {
        foreach ($request->get('questionOptions') as $item) {
            $opts = [];
            if (empty($item['id'])) {
                $option = new SurveyQuestionOption();
                $option->survey_question_id = $preg->id;

                $opts[] = $item['id'];
            } else if (!empty($item['id'])) {
                $option = SurveyQuestionOption::findOrFail($item['id']);

                $opts[] = $item['id'];
            } 
            $option->option = $item['option'];
            $option->save();
        }
    }

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

Currently I'm not checking for if its being removed, because like I said I'm not sure how, my idea was creating an array and storing the ids of the ones being created or edited and somehow using that to compare to the array of options being sent to the controller from the vue. Not sure how viable this is, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If i understood correctly, your issue is that the user can have multiple values, and on edit you can't keep track of which are kept & which are deleted ! if this is the case! just over-write everything , what i mean, after the user edits, remove everything and only keep the answers after the edit (delete + reinsert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I arrived at

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = SurveyQuestion::findOrFail($id);
    $preg->question = $request->question;
    $preg->survey_section_id = $request->survey_section_id;
    $preg->response_type_id = $request->response_type_id;
    $preg->optional = $request->optional;
    $preg->save();

    $ids = [];
    if ($request->get('questionOptions')) {
        foreach ($request->get('questionOptions') as $item) {
            if (empty($item['id'])) {
                $option = new SurveyQuestionOption();
                $option->survey_question_id = $preg->id;
             } else if (!empty($item['id'])) {
                $option = SurveyQuestionOption::findOrFail($item['id']);
            }
            $option->option = $item['option'];
            $option->save();
            $ids[] = $option['id'];
        }
    }
    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        SurveyQuestionOption::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->where('survey_question_id', $preg->id)->delete();
    }

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```